# can postgres return the names of tables participating in a query?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I would like to create an express middleware function that examines a sql string (could be either select/insert/update/delete) and extracts the names of the participating tables in the query.

for specific tables I would then have the middleware function add conditions based on application's permission definitions.

I see for select statements I could use views and extract the information from information_schema.view_table_usage. can I extract this info for arbitrary sql ?

Comment: That's a good one. You can find out the names of tables from which columns are returned in the select-list via metadata returned in the protocol, but I'm not sure about all tables touched by the query. It's known to the executor in the query plan's range table list, but I don't know if it's exposed to SQL...

Comment: is there no way to request an explanation plan that returns result in a  tabular format and try to analyse the output ?

Comment: Sure. You can get XML, json,  yaml, etc.  See 'format' option to 'explain'

Comment: this could work very nice @Craig, but as Hans-Jürgen Schönig mentioned, if the select uses a function, it will hide the tables, in which case analyzing output of the explain will not do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

basically you can only check return data. BUT: let us assume the following query ...

```
SELECT function();
```

function() is a blackbox ... it can touch anything anywhere. so, you can inspect the return data and maybe identify a table but you can certainly not see, what has been used inside the query to actually get to the result.

Comment: And to extend on this, the only infrastructure reported from a query is a list of the resulting columns names with their type details, nothing else. This is pretty much standard across any relational database.